Prove that $V(I(X)) = X$

Let $A$ be a ring and $X \subset SpecA$ a closed set.
Prove that $I(X) := \bigcap P \in XP$ is a radical ideal.

My proof is as follows:
$I(X)$ is an ideal since it's the intersection of ideals. If $f^n \in I(X)$, then $f^n \in P$ for all $P \in X$. Since $P$ is a prime ideal, $f \in P$ for all $P \in X$, implying that $f \in I(X)$. Therefore, $I(X)$ is radical.
Is this correct?

Now, prove that $V(I(X)) = X$.

Since $V(I)$ represents the closed sets in the Zariski topology and $X$ is a closed set, then $X \subset V(I(X))$.
How can I prove the other inclusion?

Does this answer your question? Why does $V(I(S))=\overline{S}$?
